# How do I configure my Gradle build to use Querydsl jakarta?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, gradle, build, querydsl

I have the following gradle build:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0'
sourceCompatibility = 17
targetCompatibility = 17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2022.0.2'
    }
}

sourceSets {
  generated {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main']
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest' 
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta'
    annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta'
    
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    runtimeOnly 'de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:3.0.2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

When I try to build the project, I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/Entity
>
> 2023-05-10T11:55:22.519-0500 [ERROR]
> [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
> com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor.createConfiguration(JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:37)

JPA 3.1 specifically `jakarta.persistence.Entity` via `jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar` is transitively brought by the spring-boot-start-data-jpa 3.0.6 dependency. So, why gradle complaining about the class not being found when referenced by Querydsl? How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try add this line to a dependencies section:

```
annotationProcessor "jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0"
```